# Create HISTFILE in subshell

Tags: bash, shell, command-history

Here is my HISTFILE:

```
$ echo $HISTFILE
/home/Steven/.bash_history
```

I can create it by using exit:

```
$ [ -e $HISTFILE ]; echo $?
1

$ exit

$ [ -e $HISTFILE ]; echo $?
0
```

However if I exit a subshell, it is not created:

```
$ [ -e $HISTFILE ]; echo $?
1

$ (exit)

$ [ -e $HISTFILE ]; echo $?
1
```

Why is the history file not getting created in a subshell?

Comment: The subshell is not an interactive shell.

Comment: @jordanm but `bash -ic exit` does not work either

Comment: Yes, it seems that `-c` is the reason for that. Try: `bash -i <<< "somecommand"`

Comment: This seems to work too `echo : | bash -i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a bash shell is opened, it is passed the content of the history file. When it exits, it appends its history to the history file.

If you open another (interactive) bash shell (in the same terminal window), execute a few commands or only `exit`, the commands (or only `exit`) will be appended to the history file.

If you however run a non-interactive sub-shell, history is turned off and environment variable `HISTFILE` will be unset.

You can verify that by running `(bash -c 'echo x$HISTFILE')` or just `bash -c 'echo x$HISTFILE'`. This will only echo `x`, proving that variable `HISTFILE` is unset in the sub-shell. (I've only added the `x` to have some visible output from the echo command.)

(The reason for `bash -c` and the single quotes it to prevent shell variable expansion in the parent shell. If you run `(echo x$HISTFILE)`, shell variable expansion will pass the value of `HISTFILE` to the sub-shell, which it then echos, making it look like it is set in the sub-shell).

So when running a sub-shell, history is turned off and variable `HISTFILE` is unset. When the sub-shell exits, nothing is appended to the history.  That is exactly what you are seeing.

You can force the sub-shell to write its history to the history file:

```
$ history -w  # write current history
$ wc -l $HISTFILE  # count lines in history file
32 /home/anyuser/.bash_history

$ bash -c 'export HISTFILE=~/.bash_history'
$ wc -l $HISTFILE
32 /home/anyuser/.bash_history

$ bash -c 'export HISTFILE=~/.bash_history;history -w'
$ wc -l $HISTFILE
0 /home/anyuser/.bash_history
```

The last sub-shell command (the one with `history -w`) overwrites the existing history file with the history of the sub-shell, which is empty because history is turned off in a non-interactive sub-shell.